# How to add a text in the checkout page woocomerce?

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to add a text in the checkout page in this part:
[image: checkoutpage]

I tried to use this hook:

```
function wh_test_1($order_id) { //<--check this line

    //create an order instance
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id); //<--check this line

    $paymethod = $order->payment_method_title;
    $orderstat = $order->get_status();
    echo "teste";
}
```

but the word "teste" appear in this part:

[image: checkout2]

Somone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. You can use the hook `woocommerce_before_thankyou` hook to add some html before "Obrigado. Seu pedido foi recebido" or you can replace the that thankyou text with any html you want with the hook `woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text`

If you want to use [woocommerce_before_thankyou](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-checkout-thankyou.html#source-view.26) (NOTE: this hook will fire also on failed orders, but you can check inside the hook if the order is failed with the *$order_id*):

```
function test_hook_before_thankyou($order_id) {
    echo "teste";
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_thankyou', 'test_hook_before_thankyou' );
```

If you want to replace that text with the hook [woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-checkout-thankyou.html#source-view.42):

```
function test_hook_replace_thankyou ( $thank_you_msg, $order_obj) { /* here you have the full order object, no only the id */

    $thank_you_msg =  'This is your new thank you message';
    $thank_you_msg .=  '<br><b>You can add html too</b>';
    return $thank_you_msg;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'test_hook_replace_thankyou' );
```